# Enable component based on selection in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have a requirement to enable a component based on selection in the page. Below is the screenshot of my page

[image: LookupController]

below lookup box should be enabled and when these two selections are made, next button should be enabled.

As of now, they are not dependent on any selections.

Below is my LWC code:

LookupController apex class:

```
public with sharing class LookupController {
    public LookupController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<SObJectResult> getResults(String ObjectName, String fieldName, String value) {
        List<SObJectResult> sObjectResultList = new List<SObJectResult>();
        system.debug(fieldName+'-------------'+ObjectName+'---++----------'+value);
        if(String.isNotEmpty(value))
            for(sObject so : Database.Query('Select '+fieldName+' FROM '+ObjectName+' WHERE '+fieldName+' LIKE \'%' + value + '%\'')) {
                String fieldvalue = (String)so.get(fieldName);
                sObjectResultList.add(new SObjectResult(fieldvalue, so.Id));
            }

        return sObjectResultList;
    }

    public class SObJectResult {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String recName;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id recId;

        public SObJectResult(String recNameTemp, Id recIdTemp) {
            recName = recNameTemp;
            recId = recIdTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

LookupController LWC HTML:

```
<template>
    <br>
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Operation</legend>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <span class="slds-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-43" value="radio-43" name="default" checked="" />
      <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-43">
        <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Insert</span>
      </label>
    </span>
            <span class="slds-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-44" value="radio-44" name="default" />
      <label class="slds-radio__label" for="radio-44">
        <span class="slds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Update</span>
      </label>
    </span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br><br>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:search" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            Search Objects below
        </h3>
        <div slot="footer">

        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="slds-form-element">


                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-combobox_container">

                        <div class={txtclassname} data-id="resultBox" aria-expanded="False" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">

                                <div>
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon iconheight">
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <lightning-input required={required} read-only={inputReadOnly} data-id="userinput" label={Label} name="searchText" onchange={searchField} value={selectRecordName} class="leftspace"></lightning-input>

                                <div if:true={iconFlag}>
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right iconheight">
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:search" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div if:true={clearIconFlag}>
                                    <button class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-button slds-button_icon iconheight" onclick={resetData}>
                                        <lightning-icon class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:clear" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Clear</span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Second part display result -->
                            <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                                <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                                    <template for:each={searchRecords} for:item="serecord">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" key={serecord.recId}>

                                            <div data-id={serecord.recId} data-name={serecord.recName} onclick={setSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                                <span class="slds-media__figure">
                                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                                                        <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="slds-media__body">
                                                    <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{serecord.recName}</span>
                                                    <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">{objectName} • {serecord.recName}</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </template>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div if:true={messageFlag}>
                                No result found.
                            </div>
                            <div if:true={LoadingText}>
                                Loading...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <br> <br>
    <a class="slds-button slds-button_brand" href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a>
</template>
```

JS Code:

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import getResults from '@salesforce/apex/LookupController.getResults';


export default class LwcCustomLookup extends LightningElement {
    @api objectName = 'EntityDefinition';
    @api fieldName = 'QualifiedApiName';
    @api selectRecordId = '';
    @api selectRecordName;
    @api Label;
    @api searchRecords = [];
    @api required = false;
   //   @api iconName = 'standard:event'
    @api LoadingText = false;
    @track txtclassname = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
    @track messageFlag = false;
    @track iconFlag =  true;
    @track clearIconFlag = false;
    @track inputReadOnly = false;


    searchField(event) {
        var currentText = event.target.value;
        this.LoadingText = true;

        getResults({ ObjectName: this.objectName, fieldName: this.fieldName, value: currentText  })
            .then(result => {
                this.searchRecords= result;
                this.LoadingText = false;

                this.txtclassname =  result.length > 0 ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
                if(currentText.length > 0 && result.length == 0) {
                    this.messageFlag = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.messageFlag = false;
                }

                if(this.selectRecordId != null && this.selectRecordId.length > 0) {
                    this.iconFlag = false;
                    this.clearIconFlag = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.iconFlag = true;
                    this.clearIconFlag = false;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

    setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var currentRecId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        this.iconFlag = false;
        this.clearIconFlag = true;
        this.selectRecordName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        this.selectRecordId = currentRecId;
        this.inputReadOnly = true;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selectName, currentRecId}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    resetData(event) {
        this.selectRecordName = "";
        this.selectRecordId = "";
        this.inputReadOnly = false;
        this.iconFlag = true;
        this.clearIconFlag = false;

    }

}
```

Is there any way I can enable the components based on other component selections. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of [getters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter) which are reevaluated once an observable property changes. Please see the playground example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JuQ76P7HJ/1/edit).

Component:

```
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
                        label="Radio Group"
                        options={options}
                        value={value}
                        onchange={handleChange}
                        type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>

    <div onkeyup={handleKeyUp}>
        <lightning-input
            name="enter-search"
            label="This will be your lookup"
            disabled={isDisabled}
            type="search"
        ></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <p if:true={queryTerm}>
        Searched for {queryTerm}!
    </p>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleInputSearch extends LightningElement {
    queryTerm;
    value = '';

    handleKeyUp(evt) {
        const isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13;
        if (isEnterKey) {
            this.queryTerm = evt.target.value;
        }
    }

    get isDisabled() {
        return !this.value;
    }


    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Sales', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'Force', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way I can display the action and selected lookup value below on the page. Like if Insert (radio button) is selected and Account from Lookup is selected, we need to display "Account object is selected for Insertion". Is there any way to do so. Please suggest

Comment: Yes, you can use a getter function

Comment: Thanks @manjit :)